# error with in_array for checking the format of Images

Tags: php

I have seen the other questions answers, so I separated the explode function but still giving the below error. I have pasted the whole code of file upload.

> Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\hiddenprocess.php on line 22

Warning: end() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\hiddenprocess.php on line 25

Here is the code:

```
    <?php




    if (empty($_FILES['Upload_Property_Images']['name']))
    {
        echo 'You have\'nt Entered Value for upload field'; 
    }

    else

    {


foreach($_FILES as $file) 

{

 // Allowed file types
 $whitelist = array("jpg","png");
 $temp = explode('.', $file['name']);
  // Match uploaded file extension

  if (in_array(end($temp), $whitelist )) 

  {
       // Count total uploads
       if (count($_FILES['Upload_Property_Images']['name'])==6) 
       {
         // Code for uploading here
          echo 'files uploaded successfully';
       } 

       else 
       {
       // Count error 
         echo 'You\'r Only Allowed Six Images';
       }

  } 



  else 
  {
       // File extension error
       echo 'Your Only Allowed JPG and PNG';
  }


 }

}

?>
```

Comment: Is your form's input named `type="file" name="Upload_Property_Images"` and does it contain `enctype="multipart/form-data"`? or `name="Upload_Property_Images[]"` - If any one of those is missing or mispelled, your code will fail.

Comment: ya it contains "enctype="multipart/form-data" and also name is like this "name="Upload_Property_Images[]" here is my file code "<input type="file" name="Upload_Property_Images[]" multiple="multiple"/>"

Comment: Plus, you have `method="post"`?

Comment: Check the value of `$file['Upload_Property_Images']['name']`

Comment: You want to upload files to a folder, right? If so, you're missing [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) and the folder location. @user3610629

Comment: @Fred-ii- ya it contains method=post

Comment: Try to `echo end($temp);` to make sure you're getting the file extension.

Comment: Do you actually need to support multiple file uploads (I noticed you're using the array style input name `Upload_Property_Images[]`)? The way PHP handles the resulting array in `$_FILES` is [confusing and clunky](http://php.net/manual/features.file-upload.multiple.php).

Comment: ya i m uploading 6 images at a time

Comment: Did you read [`this comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23508937/error-with-in-array-for-checking-the-format-of-images#comment36055904_23508937)?

Comment: @alfasin- i have  echo end($temp); inside the IF class but no result

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23508695/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working version of your code. I made a total of four changes, marked in the comments with `**`

```
if (empty($_FILES['Upload_Property_Images']['name']))
{
    echo 'You have\'nt Entered Value for upload field';
    exit(); 
}
else
{
    foreach($_FILES['Upload_Property_Images']['name'] as $file) // **CHANGED
    {
        if ($file) // **ADDED
        { 
            // Allowed file types
            $whitelist = array("jpg","png");
            $temp = explode('.', $file); // **CHANGED

            // Match uploaded file extension
            if (in_array(end($temp), $whitelist )) 
            {
                // Count total uploads
                if (count($_FILES) <= 6) // **CHANGED
                {
                    // Code for uploading here
                    echo 'files uploaded successfully';
                } 
                else 
                {
                    // Count error 
                    echo 'Your Only Allowed Six Images';
                }
            } 
            else 
            {
               // File extension error
               echo 'Your Only Allowed JPG and PNG';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed but now got this error " Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\hiddenprocess.php on line 21

Warning: end() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\hiddenprocess.php on line 24
Your Only Allowed JPG and PNG "

Comment: Hang on... let me think about this. I know the answer has to do with this, though...

Comment: @user3610629 Hmmm i don't know, try adding `print_r($file['name'])` at the very beginning of the `foreach` and tell me what you get

Comment: When uploading multiple files using the same input name (`Upload_Property_Images[]`), the resulting array looks [like this](http://php.net/manual/features.file-upload.multiple.php#53240). Each `name`, `type`, etc entry is an array

Comment: I Have changed to $temp = explode('.', implode($file['name'])); by adding an implode its working perfectly but when i submit its not counting the images if i submit even 7 images it gives me that error msg 'You'r Only Allowed Six Images'

Comment: Try changing to `count($_FILES['Upload_Property_Images']['name'])==6`

Comment: @user3610629 **Don't** implode it, you need to loop through each file name and check if they have the correct extension.

Comment: ya working now...but whenever i m submitting the file upload empty its not giving error msg that its empty means there is a problem with this lines " if (empty($_FILES['Upload_Property_Images']['name']))
    {
        echo 'You have\'nt Entered Value for upload field'; 
    }"

Comment: @I Can Has Cheezburger: i did not get u ?

Comment: @I Can Has Cheezburger: i got u i have removed the implode but showing the following errors " Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\hiddenprocess.php on line 22

Warning: end() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\hiddenprocess.php on line 25 "

Comment: @user3610629 It would be better if you update your question with the modified code.

Comment: @user3610629 I think I have fixed the problem. There were several small problems. The script should work now. See my update

Comment: @Mark M: the code you posted with four changes i got and executed but try to select two GIF and Four JPG see what will happen it will fail.

Comment: @user3610629 It doesn't fail. It will accept the four JPGs and reject the two GIFs. The logic of your code does not do what you want it to do. Your question in this post has been answered. You should accept this answer and use the code I provided to create a new question, regarding changes to the logic of the upload script - something like "How do I prevent this upload script from executing if it does not have the appropriate input" or something like that. I will be glad to help you with that, but we have gone past the scope of this post's question, which has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
foreach($_FILES['Upload_Property_Images']['name'] as $file) {
    ...
    $temp = explode('.', $file);   // not $file['name']
    ...
}
```

Comment: its working but if i upload two GIF image and Four JPG i get this massages ' You'r Only Allowed JPG and PNG
You'r Only Allowed JPG and PNG
files uploaded successfully
files uploaded successfully
files uploaded successfully
files uploaded successfully '

Comment: @user3610629 Please see my updated answer. It solves all of the problems we have been going through, including the one you just mentioned

Comment: @user3610629 well I can't see what output you are expecting

Comment: @lulco: if from six images one of them is GIF so it must not upload the all images and only once should give error massage.

Comment: @user3610629 ok so i think you should write some "validation" function which will check all your files and if it find no errors, then start to upload images

Comment: @lulco : As you now i m in beginner level would you please guide me.

Comment: @user3610629 I add an example of validation function. You can try it

Answer (score 0):

example of function for validate images:

```
function validate()
{
    $errors = array();
    foreach($_FILES['Upload_Property_Images']['name'] as $file) // **CHANGED
    {
        if ($file) // **ADDED
        { 
            // Allowed file types
            $whitelist = array("jpg","png");
            $temp = explode('.', $file); // **CHANGED

            // Match uploaded file extension
            if (in_array(end($temp), $whitelist )) 
            {
                // Count total uploads
                if (count($_FILES) > 6) // **CHANGED
                {
                    // Count error 
                    $errors[] = 'Your Only Allowed Six Images';
                }
            } 
            else 
            {
               // File extension error
               $errors[] = 'Your Only Allowed JPG and PNG';
            }
        }
    }
    if (empty($errors))
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return array_unique($errors);
    }
}

$validation = validate();
if ($validation === TRUE)
{
    // uplaod images here
}
else
{
    print_r($validation);
}
```

Comment: how to remove these "Array ( [0] =>" from output i used echo but giving out put 'Array'

Comment: use foreach($validation as $error) { echo $error . '<br />'; } instead of print_r($validation);

Comment: problem is not solved its showing the both successful and error massage

Comment: well, do not add successful message to $error array. I removed it from my code